# tcolorbox inside footnote

Tags: errors, footnotes, tcolorbox

I'm wondering if it's possible to put a tcolorbox environment inside a footnote. If I do it, I'll get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
```

The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\title{tcolorbox dentro footnote}
\author{gennaroarguzzi }
\date{October 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Se la variabile aleatoria (discreta) $X = I_{A}$ è la funzione indicatrice\footnote{
\begin{tcolorbox}[float, title=aaa]
aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
} 
di un evento A, cioè se $X$ vale $1$ se e solo se A si realizza ($\lbrace X = 1 \rbrace = A$)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show a small example of what you tried.

Comment: Hi @StevenB.Segletes I edited my question

Comment: Get rid of the word `float` in the options specification.  A footnote cannot contain a float

Comment: Perfect @StevenB.Segletes now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a footnote cannot contain a floating object (a "float"), merely removing the word "float" from the `tcolorbox` option is sufficient to allow compilation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\title{tcolorbox dentro footnote}
\author{gennaroarguzzi }
\date{October 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Se la variabile aleatoria (discreta) $X = I_{A}$ è la funzione indicatrice\footnote{
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=aaa]
aaa
\end{tcolorbox}
} 
di un evento A, cioè se $X$ vale $1$ se e solo se A si realizza ($\lbrace X = 1 \rbrace = A$)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]